# Factors affecting need to consider when using jmeter tool

Tags: jmeter

I would like to know which are the factors i need to consider when using jmeter, Most of the time internet speed will be varying and due to which i don't get accurate response time, and operations on server side [CPU utilization, etc]. 
    Do I need to consider all this points when calculating performance of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to "internet speed vary", JMeter is smart enough to detect it and report as **Latency** metric. As per [JMeter glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Latency**.
>
> JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client

So you should be able to subtract latency from the overall response time and calculate the time, required to process your request on the server side. However it will be much better if JMeter load generators will live in the same intranet. If you need to test your application behavior when virtual users are sitting on different network types [it can also be simulated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)

In regards to other factors that matter:

- Application under test health. You should be monitoring baseline server-side health metrics to identify whether application server(s) gets overloaded during the load test as i.e. if you see high response times the reason could be as simple as a lack of free RAM or slow hard-drive or whatever.
- JMeter load generator(s) health. The same approach should be applicable to JMeter engine(s). If JMeter hosts are overloaded they cannot generate the requests and send them fast enough which will be reported as reduced throughput.

  You can use [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for both. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for detailed description of the plugin installation and usage
- Your tests need to be realistic and represent virtual user as close to real one as possible. So make sure you:

  - Add [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to your test plan to represent "think time"
  - If you are testing web-based application consider adding and properly configuring [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and [Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager). Also don't forget to configure [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to "Retrieve all embedded resources" and use "Parallel pool" for this.